# When do I reuse or create a new Builder

Tags: design-patterns, web-development, builder-pattern

I've implemented a Builder Pattern in a project I'm working on.

I'm using this design pattern to created Fields and Components (div, tables, panel (boostrap)).

So I have a Director Component class. It makes a order for a Builder (in this case InputComponentBuilder)

```javascript
class @DirectorComponent

    @builder = null

    @make = (args...)->
        @builder.make.apply(@builder, args)
        @setResult(result = @builder.getResult())
        return result

    @makeInput = (name, properties)->
        @builder = new InputComponentBuilder()
        return @make.apply(@, arguments)
```

#### Source of InputComponent Builder

```javascript
class @InputComponentBuilder extends Builder

    constructor : ()->
        @input = new InputComponent()

    make : (name, properties)->
        @input.extend(properties)
        @input.setName(name)
        obj = $("<input />")
        obj.attr("name", name)
        obj.val(@input.value)
        if @input.placeholder
            obj.attr("placeholder", @input.placeholder)
        obj = BuilderHelper.applyProperties(@input, obj)
        obj = BuilderFieldHelper.applyProperties(@input, obj)
        @input.setObject(obj)
        @setResult(@input)
        return @input
```

The InputComponentBuilder is for generic input fields. So if I want to create specific field like (EmailField, ZipCodeField.. etc) I will need to create another builder extended a `InputComponetBuilder`? or in class `Director` I will need to create another method `makeZipCodeField` and change the recipe sent to InputBuilder?

## Base Class (Base class of Class Builder's result)

```javascript
class @Component

    constructor : ()->
        @id = null
        @name = ""
        @obj = null
        @attrs = {}
        @classes = []
        @css = {}

    extend : (data)->
        $.extend(@, data)

    getObject : ()->
        return @obj

    setObject : (obj)->
        @obj = obj

    setName : (name)->
        @name = name

    getName : ()->
        return @name

    getPropertiesFromObjectComponent : (args...)->
        result = []
        console.log(args, arguments)
        for key, arg of args
            console.log key, arg
            result.push(if arg of @ then @[arg] else null)
        console.log(result)
        return result
```

## Abstract Class for Fields

```javascript
class @FieldComponentAbstract extends Component
    constructor : ()->
        super
        @label = null
        @placeholder = null
        @onclick = null
        @onchange = null
        @onfocus  = null
        @onkeypressed = null
        @onkeyup = null
        @onkeydown = null
        @oninsertednode = null
        @bootstrap = null
        @onblur = null
        @mask = null

    @validate : ()->
        return true
```

### InputComponent Class

```javascript
    class @InputComponent extends FieldComponentAbstract

        constructor : ()->
            super
            @type = "text"
            @value = ""
```

## Calling makeInput

```javascript
@cpf_field = DirectorComponent.makeInput('cpf',
                placeholder: "CPF",
                mask : '999.999.999-99'
                bootstrap: true
            )
```

Comment: Very bad english makes it hard to make sense of the question or improve it.

Comment: It's Coffescript

Comment: I am not familiar with Coffescript but from what I can decipher this might not be a proper [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to begin with. In general, a Builder is used to set a large number of properties that are required to set an object. That is, rather than a constructor with 20 parameters, you make 20 calls to a Builder's methods. You end the chain with a call to a method that returns the constructed object. Is that what your code example is doing?

Comment: I set all argument in @input.extend(properties). it do include properties to object.

Comment: I added the other classes @Snowman

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question (in title), a Builder is by definition a very stateful object, so after issuing the final "build" and obtaining the constructed object, the Builder is discarded - never re-used.

Comment: StringBuilder is reused quite a lot, it's never in a "final"state internally.

Comment: True. I should have said: "never re-used in a new context"